# Facebook Analytics For Apps Export API Request Running For Almost 20 hours

Tags: facebook, facebook-analytics

I have created a request to export app events using **POST** and did get a **FB ID** for the export job created. Now when I poll using a **GET** Url as specified in the docs, I see that it shows '**RUNNING**', its has been almost **20 hours** now, is this **normal**? below is what gets **returned**.

{
   "id": "231136770698184",
   "start_ts": "2017-04-12T23:04:26+0000",
   "end_ts": "2017-04-12T23:21:06+0000",
   "status": "RUNNING",
   "column_names": [
      "server_time",
      "event_name",
      "client",
      "app_version",
      "numeric_data",
      "event_log_time",
      "custom1",
      "custom2",
      "custom3",
      "custom4",
      "custom5",
      "custom6",
      "custom7",
      "custom8",
      "custom9",
      "custom10",
      "custom11",
      "custom12",
      "custom13",
      "custom14",
      "custom15",
      "custom16",
      "custom17",
      "custom18",
      "custom19",
      "custom20",
      "custom21",
      "custom22",
      "custom23",
      "custom24",
      "custom25",
      "analytics_app_id",
      "ad_tracking_enabled",
      "usd_amount",
      "ext_user_agent",
      "ext_device_model",
      "ext_device_os",
      "timezone",
      "ext_carrier",
      "screen_dimensions",
      "total_disk_gb",
      "remaining_disk_gb",
      "invoking_ui_element",
      "is_device_id_anonymous",
      "raw_advertiser_id"
   ]
}

-Thanks
SM

Comment: There was something going with the internal servers at FB which was causing the delay, Now things are good on this end so far :)